# Django. Customize action for model

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I need to edit the "Add Object" action in the admin. It needs to redirect the user to a custom cause the logic required for adding objects is too complex to be managed in the admin. So, how do I make this possible? i.e:

[image]

The picture shows a django-suit admin, but the question is the same. How can I make that button redirect to a custom url? Or, how can I create a similar button that redirects to a custom url (I could disable the default create and leave only the custom button).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Override `change_list_template` html, the block `object-tools-items`. It's where add button is placed.

```
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    change_list_template = 'change_list.html'
```

In your `change_list.html`

```
{% extends "admin/change_list.html" %}
{% load i18n admin_static admin_list %}

{% block object-tools-items %}
        {% if has_add_permission %}
        <li>
          <a href="your/custom/url" class="addlink">
            {% blocktrans with cl.opts.verbose_name as name %}Add {{ name }}{% endblocktrans %}
              </a>
        </li>
        {% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

You need to add your new html in any dir that is included on `TEMPLATE_DIRS` options. But, you should do it inside your model's app.

```
-app
    -templates
         -admin
              change_list.html
```

Add above dir in TEMPLATE DIRS paths.

Comment: Thanks man, just one quick question, where should I place the `change_list.html` file?

Comment: @alejoss check my answer. I Updated it